# Did the past occur or is it occurring relatively, and will the future occur or is it occurring relatively?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics, physics

Did the day I was born occur already, or is it occurring relatively to me in the past?

Will the day I die occur or is it occurring relatively to me in the future?

I know that some physicists are playing around with the idea of time flow vs non time flow, and I wanted to get any kind of references or ideas from a philosophical aspect.

*Using the word relatively has nothing to do with the theorems of general and special relativity.

Comment: You may want to look into McTaggart on the A-theory and the B-theory of time at https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/ which basically concerns the question of whether there is an objective present moment (the A theory) or if terms like "present, past, and future" are purely relational (the B theory), like spatial terms such as "here" or "to the north" and "to the south". Related to this is presentism vs. eternalism, where a presentist believes only present things exist and an eternalist believes past things and future things are equally real.

Comment: Another good intro is at https://www.rep.routledge.com/articles/thematic/time-metaphysics-of/v-2 -- see the box labeled "Contents" at the left for the different sections of the article

Comment: @Hypnosifi Both are great!!

Answer (score 1):

My limited opinion on this matter, picking a line from Hypnosil's linked page, [Time & Physics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/#TimePhys) :

> "it follows from the relativity of simultaneity that there is no fact of the matter as to what is present"

Just because everything is relativised to frames, doesn't mean the present moment is not universal.  It just means it would be inaccessible.

And it seems to me more likely that the present moment *is* universal, (although I am open to contradictory information, with great interest).

***Edit 21/02/2021***

*Moved to a separate answer to allow more easily for comments.*

Comment: "It has often been commented by physicists that Einstein’s GTR {thus} reintroduced the relations of absolute simultaneity that his STR had denied. (Craig, Smith  2007: 8); same in  Jammer M., 2006. *Concepts of simultaneity*. p285.

Comment: @sand1 - Different coordinate systems with different defs of simultaneity are equally valid in general relativity just as in special relativity--p. 285 of Jammer's *Concepts of Simultaneity* says that GR does *not* have objective simultaneity, approvingly quoting Moller's comment that "in a general system of reference it is impossible to define globally standard simultaneity between any two events" (p. 284 mentions Moller as one who 'proved that there are space-time reference systems in general relativity that do not admit a global standard simultaneity')

Comment: ...as for p. 8 of the Craig/Smith reference, that's referring to the simultaneity convention commonly used in the [FLRW cosmological model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker_metric), but although that convention is the most "natural" one in that model since it ensures each surface of simultaneity has a perfectly homogenous distribution of matter, you could use a different convention and the laws of physics would be the same, it's not a 'preferred' frame in a physicist's sense. And of course the real universe has inhomogeneities no matter what convention you use.

Comment: Finally note that William Lane Craig, the co-author of the section with the comment about reintroducing relations of absolute simultaneity, is an evangelical christian philosopher who seems to believe in absolute time for religious reasons (see his lecture [here](https://www.reasonablefaith.org/videos/lectures/god-time-and-relativity-st-andrews/)), so I wouldn't take him as a reliable guide to what physicists think about absolute simultaneity (he doesn't cite any specific physicists for the claim that the simultaneity convention in simplified cosmological models supports absolute simultaneity)

Comment: Thanks for the details.  Everything can be dated with ref to the singularity 'big bang'', in a so called "cosmic time" and that looks like a physical argument, not an objection from a model.

Comment: @sand1 - But there are many timelike worldlines from the Big Bang to any given later event (say, the formation of the Earth), and different worldlines can measure different amounts of [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) between those two events. So, the fact that everything begins with the big bang is not itself enough to establish any specific universal dating system to judge how long after the big bang some event has occurred, and thus to judge which events happened the same amount of time after the big bang (i.e. a universal simultaneity standard).

Comment: @Hypnosifl Isn't worldline concern missing the point? : illustrating with the twin paradox, even when the twins are back together in the same place, one older than the other, they are still in the same moment of the present, (and perhaps the universal moment).

Comment: @ChrisDegnen - All frames agree on which events coincide in the same *local* region of spacetime (like what ages two twins will be at the moment they reunite at the same spot in space), the issue with simultaneity is that there is no frame-independent way of deciding which pairs of events at faraway locations in space happen at the "same time" (like if a person on Earth sees their twin depart when the one on Earth is age 20, and return when they're age 40, there's no frame-independent truth about what event on the traveling twin's worldline was simultaneous with the Earth twin turning 30)

Comment: Very well.  Then can we at least establish, to the best of knowledge, that the universal present moment is not actually disproved?

Comment: In general relativity, we can rule out the idea that the equations for the laws of physics will take a special preferred form if you assume a coordinate system with a special definition of simultaneity (which would be true in certain 19th century 'luminiferous aether' theories for example). It's conceivable a future theory of quantum gravity replacing GR would work like that though (but few physicists think that's likely), and even if there is no definition that's preferred according to physical measurements you are free to assume an unmeasurable metaphysical truth about simultaneity.

Comment: @Hypnosifi researching your comments, you mentioned  “the issue with simultaneity is that there is no frame-independent way of deciding which pairs of events at faraway locations in space happen at the "same time” “, which explained by Einstein and so we can better understand time, but some suggest that it is not enough to understand the flow of time, and that’s why some physicists (a few) support such theories as the “block universe”.

Comment: The block universe just considers that past, present and future are equally real, so for instance, a satellite which passed over the North Pole has trajectory as it passes over the equator on its way to the South Pole; a continuous physical event in the block model.  Nevertheless, at 12 o'clock on Earth, as the satellite is adjusting its clock (for relativistic effects), it is still in the same present moment as everything else, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

***Did the past occur or is it occurring relatively ... ?***

> "it follows from the relativity of simultaneity that there is no fact of the matter as to what is present"

Does simultaneity relate to presentism? For sure at different locations what is observed to be simultaneous differs, but that does not affect the present moment. The present moment does not have to be defined as having the same observed events happening simultaneously.  And what could anything other than the present moment even be?  Different present moments together?  That doesn't make sense.

Regions of spacetime may be unobservable, but that does not mean they drift apart temporally into variations of the present.  That would be a completely unnecessary and absurd complication.

So the answer to the above question is: the past occurs *both* absolutely and relatively to a varying degree depending on one's speed of movement through space.  There are no places where one person's past is in another's future.  They are all in the past of the present moment.

This has no bearing on the block model, which shows a real trajectory through time.  Only one time slice is the present moment.  Presentism may deny the reality of the past in a manner of speaking, but that does not stop that singular time slice in the block model being the present moment.  Presentism and eternalise are not at odds in this respect.

> the Moving Spotlight Theory is an example of an eternalist A-theory
> that subscribes to the dynamic thesis. ... Spotlighters think instead
> that there is a spacetime manifold, but one particular region of the
> manifold is objectively distinguished — the present.

Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy [The Moving Spotlight Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/#MoviSpotTheo)

> Fragmentalists (see Fine 2005) think that there is a spacetime
> manifold but that every point in the manifold has its own type of
> objective presentness, which defines a past and future relative to the
> point.

Fine's dismissal of the present [appears to rest](http://www.thomashofweber.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/fine.pdf) on special relativity's view on simultaneity, but as discussed, just because different observers do not agree on what is observed as simultaneous does not mean they are not in the same present.